# Can't link libpcrecpp w/ MinGW

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, gnu, pcre

While compiling/linking this code:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <pcrecpp.h>
using pcrecpp::RE;

int main() {
    string
        subj ("Hello world!"),
        rgx ("lolCat([0-9])"),
        result;
    RE(rgx).FullMatch(subj, &result);
}
```

... by using this command:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -std=c++11 -o test.exe -Ipcre-install/include test.cpp \
pcre-install/lib/libpcre.a \
pcre-install/lib/libpcrecpp.a \
pcre-install/lib/libpcreposix.a
```

... I get this error(s):

```
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x14b): more undefined references to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE6no_argE' follow
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK7pcrecpp2RE9FullMatchERKNS_11StringPieceERKNS_3ArgES6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_S6_'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RED1Ev'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RED1Ev'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN7pcrecpp3ArgC1EPSs[__ZN7pcrecpp3ArgC1EPSs]+0x16): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp3Arg12parse_stringEPKciPv'
/tmp/ccAR72nT.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN7pcrecpp2REC1ERKSs[__ZN7pcrecpp2REC1ERKSs]+0x6a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitERKSsPKNS_10RE_OptionsE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

`libpcrecpp` was compiled with this configuration:

```
../pcre3-8.35/configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc \
--enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes \
--prefix="$(readlink -m ../pcre-install)"
```

Comment: Maybe try the `-static` flag?

Comment: Maybe try changing the order of the libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9968496/3807729

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to link a static library using GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952146/proper-way-to-link-a-static-library-using-gcc)

Comment: Also this may help: http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.htm

Comment: Nothing of those are working for me. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have compile `pcrecpp` as static library and you need to define `PCRE_STATIC` when compiling your code, see https://github.com/vmg/pcre/blob/a257f5c7acc12e64dc2b5aa170b8e4b87dc34f83/pcreposix.h#L117

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -std=c++11 -o test.exe -DPCRE_STATIC -Ipcre-install/include test.cpp \
pcre-install/lib/libpcre.a \
pcre-install/lib/libpcrecpp.a \
pcre-install/lib/libpcreposix.a
```

Without `PCRE_STATIC` all public functions marked as [dllimport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) and have different name mangling

Answer (score 1):

You must define PCRE_STATIC (i.e. `-DPCRE_STATIC`).